# get values and keys for json response with curl

Tags: php, json

I am using curl to return json data from a service. The var dump works fine, however when i try to access a key value pair i get nothing? One of the keys is status, which is what i am trying to retrieve in my if statement.

```
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '$AgentString');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
    "Accept: application/json"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode(utf8_encode($result), true);

var_dump($json["return"]);

if (isset($json->status)) {
   // do something
   print("yes");
} else {
print("No");
}
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($json)` output?  Also, you are `var_dump`ing `$json["return"]`, but trying to access `$json->status`.

Comment: With or without return dumps the values of the json data. So it looks like this I deleteed some content for security:

string(1480) "{"response": {
 "header": {"status": "SUCCESS"},
 "table": {"rows": {"row":  {
  "SSOEnabled": false,
  "active": "",
  "authKey": "26facbec-a6e1-401a-86e1-fd4f467598d8",
  "authType": "Default Authentication",
  "authentication": null,
  }
}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the second parameter in `json_decode` is true, the result would be returned as an associative array.

```
$json->status
```

Should be

```
$json["status"]
```

Comment: Just tried that and still get nothing? I know using return stops any further actions in php, so I removed that as well to test and still did not get the value.

Comment: @JamesFerguson: You don't even get the var_dump of "title"?

Comment: Not following your question? I do have a keypair of title and all my fields show in the var dump. However accessing them im getting nothing.

Comment: ok, so if i keep my code and do this: if (isset($json["return"]["status"]))

It works. any idea on why i would require the return? Perhaps its the curl issues, not php decode issues?

Comment: @JamesFerguson: If the response is found inside of `return` (which may be the case if the other site returns it in that format), that's how you will need to access it.